# ProgressBar programmatically in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, progress-bar

I have a TabWidget with some Fragment in it. I want to show a ProgressBar inside it but the ProgressBar never show. Here my code:

```
private ProgressBar progressBar;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.roomstatusadmin_activity, container, false);

    progressBar = new ProgressBar(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), null, android.R.attr.progressBarStyleSmall);
    progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    //FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    //layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
    progressBar.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

    return view;
}
```

I read some question but there is no solution, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40699680/add-a-progressbar-programatically-to-a-fragment-in-android) . I test with add the ProgressBar into my layout.xml and the ProgressBar is show. But I will have use this ProgressBar in some layout so I realy need it programmatically.

Comment: Remove `getApplicationContext()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating a progressbar and not attaching to the view.To attach that to the frgament view find the id of the parent layout of the fargment.

```
YOURPARENTLAYOUT layout=(YOURPARENTLAYOUT)view.findViewById(R.id.yourParentLayout)
```

And add that to the parent layout at the end after creating progressbar

```
layout.addView(progressBar);
```

Comment: How to make it center horizontal and vertical?

Comment: Use  FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER; instead od relativelayout

Answer (score 2):

You have not added the Progressbar to the fragment's layout. 
Inflate your layout xml and cast to its root view. If your root view is a RelativeLayout, then :
`RelativeLayout view = (RelativeLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.roomstatusadmin_activity, container, false);`

**Now add the progressbar to the layout :** 
`view.addView(progressBar);`

Comment: are you sure? I think a `view` is a type `View` and its not have `addView` . But the `container` have `addView` but its still not work too. But I'll try thanks for answer

Comment: The `view` in my answer is a `RelativeLayout`, which is a `ViewGroup`, which contains an `addView(View v)` method.

Comment: I think there is missunderstanding. regarding my code above, `view` is a `View` and you give me answer the `view` with `Layout` type. Your answer work for me too thank you